# Print button dynamic size in console - Kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I would like to print button size in console. Able to get root window size, any idea how to get the buttons?

Hoping some way iterate through the widget ids?

.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class TestOut(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_size(self, *args):
        # print(str(self.size))
        pass


    def get_size(self):
        for key, val in self.ids.items():
            print(key, val)
        # print(self.ids.button1.size)

class PlaygroundApp(App):
    title = "test"

    def build(self):
        return TestOut()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    PlaygroundApp().run()
```

.kv

```
<TestOut>:
    Button:
        id: button1
        text: 'A'
        width: dp(100)
        size_hint: None, 1

    Button:
        id: button2
        text: 'B'
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<TestOut>:
    Button:
        id: button1
        text: 'A'
        width: dp(100)
        size_hint: None, 1
        on_release:
            print(button1.size)

    Button:
        id: button2
        text: 'B'
        on_release:
            print(button2.size)
```